# Can a custom to_s method be created for a specific association collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have an `Entry` model which `has_many :tags`. I want to be able to list my tags in an text input (ie. "tag-1, tag-2", etc.), however, I am running into an issue.

If I just use

```
form_for(:entry, form_options) do |f|
  f.text_field :tags
end
```

My text box gets created, but is filled with something like `#<Tag:0xb79fb584>#<Tag:0xb79faddc>`, which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

I know I can add a `to_s` method to Tag:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name # the name of the tag
  end
end
```

But that just leaves me with something like `tag-1tag-2` because `@entry.tags.to_s` still just refers to `Array#to_s`.

Right now, I am using

```
f.text_field :tags, :value => @entry.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
```

instead, which will display the correct string, but doesn't feel like the "rails way" of doing things. Is there a way I can add a custom `to_s` method specifically to my `tags` association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way to do this: virtual attributes. [This example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes) shows exactly how to deal with tag association using a virtual attribute.

Answer (score 3):

kind of hacky and terrible, but you could

```
alias_method_chain :tags, :fancy_to_s
def tags_with_fancy_to_s
  assoc = tags_without_fancy_to_s
  def assoc.to_s; map(&:name).join(", "); end
  assoc
end
```

that *should* work.

Alternatively, you could just create the method "tags_string" and have it do the same thing without abusing the object system/the maintenance coders' brains.

Comment: I'm the maintenance coder (it's a personal project), so I'm not worried about that ;). I considered just adding a `tag_names` method, but the tradeoff for that is that then I need extra code in the controller to set @entry.tags for saving.

Comment: false, define a tags_string= on the model (where it belongs) and have that handle the find or create by name standard tag stuff.  Even better, you can use acts_as_taggable_on_steroids or similar and get this all for free.